# What makes magic "dark"?

Tags: sanctuary-a-witchs-tale

In *Sanctuary: A Witch's Tale*, the term "dark magic" is frequently bandied about. Now, Abigail's protests to contrary notwithstanding, casting a spell on someone to, say, control their mind and make them stop cheating on their spouse does *not* seem to be considered dark magic. Rather, doing it to someone without their consent simply seems to be forbidden by the law and the Moot on the basis of its evident immorality.

By contrast, everything related to the *Starcrossed Grimoire* seems to be considered terrible dark magic not just by the general public, but by basically all knowledgeable witches, including Sarah Fenn herself, but (apart from such objectionable spells as death and destruction), the book also contains more innocuous elements such as spells of concealment that can be used for purposes such as defeating detection spells. And while on the one hand, many witches expressed discomfort looking at the symbols and the aftereffects of the warehouse fire spell seemed to have a life of their own, on the other hand, Sarah did not seem particularly worried about consequences of Harper *tattooing the symbols all over her body*.

What is it that makes a spell "dark magic" in the series? Is it a metaphysical category associated with corruption or something similar, or is it just based on the practical characteristics of a spell?

Comment: Generally, outside blood magic and demonology, it's whatever society disagrees with this week.

Comment: @Separatrix - Is this the case in the context of the show? There is no demonology there, as far as I am aware, and blood is used as a component in various spells, most of which do not seem to be considered dark magic.